# How to create new variables on the basis of timepoints in R

Tags: r

I have problems creating new variables `(V0, V1, V2)` based on three timepoints `(t0, t1, t2)` in a long format data set. To run my analysis I need to separate the ratings which are at the moment in one column in a long format data set separated by timepoints . However, when I try to create a new variable for each timepoint, I obtain values for all three timepoints in each of the new variables instead of only the selected ones or an error message. Or instead of creating a new variable with only the scores of e.g. `t0`, all measurements in the df of `t1` and `t2` are excluded, probably due to the filter function I used. Probably the problem is also that my data is at the moment in the long format and the variables I try to create should be in a wide format.

I tried different variants of the following code:

```
NewVar1 <- df %>% group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(NewVar1=Score[timepoint=="t0"]) %>% filter(timepoint!= "t1") %>% filter(N_cycle_phase!= "t2")
```

This, I did for the three timepoints respectively.
I would be very grateful for any suggestions how to tackle this problem.

Comment: What are all of the variables in your dataset?

Comment: If this answer works for you, could you mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what all your variables are but using reshape should work.

```
df%>%
dcast(variables_in_your_data_set_to_not_change ~ variable_to_change_to_width, value.var = "variable_name_of_values_to_be_changed")
```

so something like

```
df%>%dcast(subject ~ timepoint, value.var = "Score")
```

If you have other variables in your dataset, just add them after subject like subject + var2 + var3 ~ ... You then should have your three columns with separate timepoints.

You can rename those variables to be V0 ,V1, V2, if you want by using mutate:

```
library(dplyr)

    df%>%
    mutate(V0 = t0,
    V1 = t1,
    V2 = t2)
```